# How to fix the missing BLINDTRANSFER and ATTENDEDTRANSFER log entries in the queue_log file?

Tags: queue, asterisk, transfer

I write a wallboard for asterisk queue system. The document says that when a call is transferred away by an agent an ATTENDEDTRANSFER (or BLINDTRANSFER) event log should be added to the queue_log file automatically. Unfortunately there is no line for any transferred calls in the log file (queue_log in my case). Is there any setting to be changed to let the system to log them properly ?
When I check the CEL files, I see the transfer logs. So the system is logging correctly for CEL but not for queue_log.
I tried to transfer the call to another agent, to an IVR and to another user who is not an agent for any queue. The result is the same, no log for the transfer process.

Any suggestions ?

I use the following:
Asterisk Version: 13.22.0
Freepbx 14.0.5.25 
All trunks and clients are connected via SIP

Comment: Also transfers made via feature codes do not produce TRANSFER log entries in the queue_log.

Comment: You may want to look at https://www.queuemetrics.com/faq.jsp?uid=faq-053-transfers - please note that the FAQ itself is from  **2008**, and sadly still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your phone do transfer via internal features - no log entries.

You have parse AMI events for needed info.

Write your own queue wallboard is VERY hard task. Queue module have really alot of issues.
Can recommend read some already written modules like https://www.asternic.net or queuemetric

Comment: I also make transfers with ## feature code. The result is the same. I am ready to use another transfer method if logging will be enabled.Also tired *2, but result is the same.

Comment: There are no silver bullet for that. You can catch transfer events, or catch transfer itself in dialplan. Or file bug report and wait till something will be fixed(most likly will be removed info from doc).